# Visual Studio Code tools pane missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMOJO.png)

I can't see environmet,tools parts on the left. ın this photo, above is my program. The application in the yo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyyrE.png)utube video below

I downloaded Visual Studio 2022 but there is 2019 version in the videos.I don't know where this part is in 2022 visual studio.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40S7I.png)

Comment: Your first 2 images show Visual Studio. The last image shows Visual Studio Code which is a complete different tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
:: Windows > Reset Window layout.
```

It Will reset the Vs and set as a default VS